# What are the best frameworks to build a mobile and desktop app?

Tags: mobile, frameworks, desktop

I am looking for a framework to build an application to be compatible with mobile (browse, or better as a phonegap app) AND desktop browsers.

I notice that the frameworks are designed for one and not the other, ex. Ionic to is dedicated to mobile apps (thus desktop browser should work, it is not supported).

So are there framework that do both jobs and do it well ?

Comment: Still looking for an answer to this question a year and a half later. Did you ever come across something that suited your needs?